# what is this function for?

Tags: javascript, function

I have this function but I can't understand whatit do.

```
var myfunc = function (fn, context) {
        return function () {
            return fn.apply(context, arguments);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Start with [the explanation for `apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and work your way backwards, because this is a function that returns a function that returns an applied function, so first understand the last step.

Comment: Looks like a bad polyfill for `bind`

Comment: @Bergi not a polyfill, since it doesn't do partial application, just the `this` binding. But yeah, it's a version of `bind`